# Wordpress default post categories meta box widget

Tags: plugins, functions, categories, metabox

I have a plugin that automatically selects the categories in the wordpress post editor, sadly after installing the **Rank Math - SEO plugin** the default metabox of the post editor has changed and the plugin no longer recognizes the inputs and values to be assigned automatically.

[image]

Is there a way or function does it work to prevent override javascript and css from overwriting the wordpress category checklist metabox?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'rank_math/admin/disable_primary_term', '__return_true' );
```

found the solution!